# How to order my child pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

this is my company website [pslship](http://pslship.com/)

in this page **ABOUT US** page right menu i have 5 pages. what i want is i need to order this pages what i like. **Aboutus** page used **Default theme** and sub pages haveused different themes. so where i want make a changes and anything ideas?

this is my Aboutus page theme code for that left bar

```
 </td>
    <td width="15" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="155" valign="top"> 
    <div class="TextArea" style="padding:5px; width:145px; min-height:100%;">


<?php endwhile; endif; 
wp_reset_query();
?>     

<?php 
global $post;
$args = array('post_parent'=> '8', 'post_type'=> 'page');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php
$str =get_permalink();
$str = substr($str, ($pos = strpos($str, '?')) !== false ? $pos + 1 : 0);
?>

<div class="abtdivs2" aboutid="<?php echo $str; ?>">
  <h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
  <?php echo(types_render_field("sub-title", array("raw"=>"true")));  ?>
</div>
<hr />

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  


    </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add `orderby` and `order` fields to your `$args` array**

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent'=> '8', 
    'post_type'=> 'page',
    'orderby' => 'FIELD',
    'order' => 'DESC|ASC'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

If you look at the same page below at the description of `orderby`, you can use common fields like `ID`, `author`, `date`, etc.

Additionally you can also sort by `meta_value` and `meta_value_num`. These are additional custom fields you can add to each post.

In order to see `Custom Fields` in your posts edit page, click on `Screen Options` in the top-right corner and then on `Custom Fields`.

Like in this picture: http://www.mhthemes.com/support/files/2014/07/Custom_Excerpts.png

Then scroll down and you should see an additional area for custom fields, like here: https://codex.wordpress.org/images/7/7f/custom_field_example.jpeg

There you can add a field for `position` for instance and give each post the position you like.

In your case, something like this should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent'=> '8', 
    'post_type'=> 'page',
    'meta_key' => 'position', // references to your Custom Field
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```